# Math equation in Excel using two variables

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

Please help me this. This should be simple but I am stuck.

Lets say:

```
a=0.9162904
b=0.8473002
b-a=-0.0689902

r=-1.21E-22

pa=1 /(1+EXP(-1*(a+(r)))) = 0.714285647
pb=1 /(1+EXP(-1*(b+(r)))) = 0.700000491

pb=pa=-0.014285155
```

Now let's say that only `r` and `(b-a)` is given to me.

What is the formula to calculate `(pb-pa)`?

Comment: What does your `EXP` do?

Comment: it is the number e

Comment: Also, I meant pb-pa=-0.014285155

Comment: exp is pa=1 /(1+e^(-1*(a+(r))))

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate `pb - pa` from `b-a` and `r`. To see this let's call `d = b-a`. Then `d` is given (you cannot change it). Now, your equations can be written as

```
pa = 1 / (1 + exp(-a-r))
pb = 1 / (1 + exp(-b-r))
```

or

```
pa = 1 / (1 + exp(-r)exp(-a))
pb = 1 / (1 + exp(-r-d)exp(-a))
```

because `b = d+a`.

Now put

```
C = exp(-r)
D = exp(-r-d)
```

these two quantities are constants (i.e., they are given). However, `a` is not a constant so let's emphasize this by putting

```
x = exp(-a)
```

which means that `x` can be given any positive value. With these notations,

```
pa = 1 / (1 + C x)
pb = 1 / (1 + D x)
```

and

```
pb - pa = 1 / (1 + C x) - (1 / (1 + D x))
```

which depends on `x` for any values of `d` and `r` except the very particular case where `C = D`, which only happens if `r = 0`.

Comment: Excellent mathsing! :)